# Spring security 3.0 user authentication and authorization - page not found(404)

Tags: spring-security

I have a problem with my spring application. I want to authenticate user from DB using mybatis but after authenticating the user my defaultSuccessUrl doesn't get accessed. In Browser URL, it has my defaultSuccessUrl but can't access to default page.

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

SpringSecurity.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurity {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
        .formLogin((form) -> form
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/")
                .permitAll()
                )
        .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll())
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
        
        http.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationMannagerBean(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();        
    }

}
```

CustomUserDetailsService.java

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserInfoService gtUserInfoService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userId) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        UserInfoDto authInfo = gtUserInfoService.getAuthInfo(userId);

        if (authInfo != null) {

            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authInfo.getRole()));
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(authInfo.getUserId(), authInfo.getPassword(), authorities);

        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid UserId or Password");
        }
    }
}
```

UserController.java

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/user/")
    public String init() {
        
        
        return "fragments/TopPage";

    }
    
}
```

and under fragments folder I have my TopPage.html, Login.html

Comment: Show your controller method for `/access-denied`. I guess you didn't have it, so you have to implement it.